# Try Catch using double question mark(??) in laravel view(blade) does'nt work

Tags: php, html, laravel, web, laravel-blade

I have an issue on my script.
If i write :

```
{{ ($data->classroom??'' == $clr->id) ? 'checked' : '' }}
```

It is working.

But i can't do it, because `$data->classroom` would be parameter to compare of lists of `$clr->id` (radio button purpose).

But if i write :

```
{{ ($clr->id == $data->classroom??'') ? 'checked' : '' }}
```

The null safety(??) doesn't work.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: "does'nt working" - what does that mean? Also, how is this related to HTML itself, or [tag:web]?

Comment: A simple `@if ... @endif` wouldn't do?

Comment: it doesn't work because the null is still detected.
HTML and Blade are both same, so i put these, CMIIW

Comment: @brombeer yeah it could be, but I will try later, if i can't find out the solution for a day

Comment: IMHO it should be `{{ ($clr->id == $data->classroom?) ? 'checked' : '' }}`. The ?? is not a null safety operator, but the null coalescing operator: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The double question mark, also called null coalescing operator is, in your case, ran after the == operation. Soo if you want to achieve this, you need to put parenthesis like that:
`($clr->id == ($data->classroom??''))[...]`